# Отображение количества блоков в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть список из нескольких пунктов.

- На разрешении больше 700px должно отображаться 5 пунктов меню.
- На разрешении меньше 700px 4 пункта.
- На разрешении меньше 500px 3 пункта.

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
$('ul').each(function(){

  var $this = $(this),
      galItem = $this.find('li'),
      galL = galItem.length,
      galCount = $('#count'),
      n;

  n = 5;

  if($(window).width() < 700){
    n = 4;
  } 
  
  
  if($(window).width() < 400) {
    n = 3;
  }

  $this.find('li').css({'opacity': 0}); 
  $this.find('li').slice(0, n).css({'opacity': 1}); 

  galItem.eq(n-1).addClass('last');
  galItem.eq(n-1).find('a').append('<span class="more">еще '+(galL-n)+'</span>');

  galCount.html(galL);    

});
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.last {
  background: red;
  color:#fff;
}

.more {
  font-size:12px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<h1 id="count"></h1>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Пытаюсь задать такое условие:

```
var n;
  n = 5;

  if($(window).width() < 700){
    n = 4;
  } 

  if($(window).width() < 400) {
    n = 3;
  }
```

Вроде как работает и нормально, но при ресайзе `.last` добавляется нескольким блокам, должен только одному (если n=4, то 5-ому; если n=3, то 4-ому ...).

**Вопрос:** как реализовать динамическое изменение отображения пунктов меню в зависимости от разрешения экрана?

**P.S:** нужна реализация только jq\js (не css)

Comment: Вместо else if поставьте просто if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не работало потому что в `<li>` не было вложенных `<a>`... соответственно, выражение `galItem.eq(n-1).find('a')` возвращало пустой набор, в который нельзя добавить элементы.

Предварительно создавайте этот `<a>` с классом `.more`, и не забывайте удалять перед тем как навесить заново.

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
  $('ul').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        galItem = $this.find('li'),
        galL = galItem.length,
        galCount = $('#count'),
        vw = $(window).width(),
        n = 5;
    if (vw < 400) n = 3;
    else
      if (vw < 700) n = 4;
    galItem.css('opacity', '0'); 
    galItem.slice(0, n).css('opacity', '1');
    galItem.find('.more').remove(); 
    galItem.removeClass('last');
    galItem.eq(n-1).addClass('last');
    var more = $('<a class="more"></a>');
    more.append('<span>еще ' + (galL - n) + '</span>'); 
    galItem.eq(n-1).append(more); 
    galCount.html(galL);    
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.last {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.more {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<h1 id="count"></h1>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

В целом, решение малоэффективное, так как ресайз будет дико жрать процессорные ресурсы. Логику обработчика `resize` лучше вынести в таймаут, типа

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimeout); 
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(onResize, 500);  //  onResize() - функция-обработчик
});
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!

Comment: @HamSter,  не за что. `p.s.:` Я дополнил ответ пояснением.

Comment: c крайним интересно, `onResize` - это `function() { $('ul').each(function () { ... ` правильно понимаю?

Comment: @HamSter, да, правильно, только лучше будет поместить код в *именованную* функцию: `function onResize() { $('ul').each(function () {...}); }`, чтобы еще и для `load` ее использовать в качестве параметра: `$(window).on('load', onResize);` - тут таймаут уже не требуется.

Comment: При ресайзе просто очень много event'ов вылетает, поэтому их фильтруют таймаутом. Такой паттерн называется **debounce**.

Answer (score -1):

Можно создать блок с высотой 1 пиксель, на определенном разрешении его скрыть и в jq написать так:

```
if ($('.visible_while_not_480').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#block').removeClass('class');
        $('#block2').addClass('class');
    }
```

Костыль, но работает)